# Getting ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a big dataframe containing structure like below:

```
   id  year  QTY_SOLD  QTY_PUR  QTY_MFG
0   1  2016         9      2.0       10
1   1  2017         9      0.0       10
2   1  2018         0      2.0       10
3   1  2018         2      1         3
4   2  2016         7      2.0       11
5   2  2017         2      0.0        0
6   2  2018         0      0.0       18
```

and I created a pivot table where if the value of Quantity sold,purchased and mfg is not zero, the pivot table would look like below:

```
df['str'] = (df.iloc[:, -3:].astype(bool) * ['S', 'P', 'M']).apply(lambda x: '_'.join([v for v in x if v]), axis=1)
df_pivot = df.pivot(index='id', columns='year', values='str') 

year   2016 2017 2018
id                   
1     S_P_M  S_M  P_M
2     S_P_M    S    M
```

But I am getting below error:

```
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

Could someone tell me why this could be happening?
The dataframe is very big, I have posted only few lines.

Comment: Use `pivot_table`

Comment: I have already done that

Comment: I see `pivot` method

Comment: It is giving me pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate, so I think we need some aggfunc with it, which I am not giving and I am not sure what to put there.

Comment: Use `aggfunc='_'.join`